# Angular Joining Two Arrays and Displaying Them as a Categorized List

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, lodash

In my code, I call two json objects using fromFetch method. I can get them separately and display them as an array on the console. The categoryId of the items$ is the same with the id of categories$. I want to join them and, display them as a single array by grouping them by category$.name. I tried the approach below but it didn't work, what should I do to achieve this?
TS:

```
items$: Observable<Item[]>;
  categories$: Observable<Category[]>;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Item>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['categoryId', 'name', 'quantityPerUnit'];

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.items$ = fromFetch(
      'https:items.json'
    ).pipe(
      switchMap((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
    );

    this.items$.subscribe(function (result) {
      const grouped = _.groupBy(result, (res) => res.categoryId);
      this.dataSource = result;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      console.log(grouped);
    });

    this.categories$ = fromFetch(
      'https:categories.json'
    ).pipe(
      switchMap((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
    );

    this.categories$.subscribe(function (data) {
      // const categoryGrouped = _.groupBy(result, (res) => res.name);
      console.log(data);
    });

    var merged = _.merge(_.keyBy(this.items$, 'categoryId'), _.keyBy(this.categories$, 'id'));
    var values = _.values(merged);
    console.log(values);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lodash version. You can also do a clone deep of loadash, so that there are no reference errors. like shown below.

let output = cloneDeep(element);

We need to do `forkJoin` to get both the api calls and merge them!

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

displayedColumns: string[] = ['categoryId', 'name', 'quantityPerUnit'];

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.items$ = fromFetch('https:items.json').pipe(
        switchMap(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
    );

    this.categories$ = fromFetch('https:categories.json').pipe(
        switchMap(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
    );
    forkJoin([this.items$, this.categories$]).subscribe(([items, categories]: Array<any>) => {
        const finalArray: Array<any>= [];
        items.forEach((element: any) => {
            let output = {...element};
            const foundCategory = categories.find(x => x.categoryId === element.categoryId);
            if(foundCategory) {
                output = {...output, ...foundCategory};
            }
            finalArray.push(output);
        });
        this.dataSource = finalArray;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you but it didn't work :/. I'm trying to print the array on to the console so, I said console.log(finalArray) at the end. But, it gave a Unexpected token < in JSON error

Comment: @RocketMonkey Please console.log and check where its going wrong, this pattern will surely help you!

Comment: okay, now an array is returned but again, I can only see the items array. Item and categories array did not merge

Comment: @RocketMonkey Since I dont have the data, I cant debug for you, just do a check in chrome debugger!

Comment: okay, i found the problem with the array. Inside categories.json, I have name and id attribute but I also have those attributes in the items.json. With this code, the id and name of the items.json becomes the id and name of the category (not talking about the categoryId in items.json). How can I fix that?

Comment: @RocketMonkey create a new property in the object, like id of category becomes `categoryId` and `categoryName`, then delete the properties `id` and `name` using the command `delete foundCategory.id` and `delete foundCategory.name`, after deleting when you merge the original properties will be reserved!